# how do i print this sentence in brackets and with quotation marks around each word?

Tags: python, brackets

```
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence:")

words = sentence.split()

position= [0]

myList = [] 

[myList.append(x) for x in words if x not in myList]

a =(" ".join(myList))

print (a)
```

This piece of code allows the user to input a sentence and it removes duplicated words. When the program outputs the sentence it outputs the sentence like this:

For example, if my sentence was 'I like python' my program would print 
`I like python` onto the screen

What I need help with is that I want the program to output:

```
['I', 'like', 'python']
```

Any suggestions please

Comment: Your post title says _with quotation marks around each word_, but your post says your desired output is `[I, like, python]`, which does _not_ have quotation marks.  So which is it?

Comment: Is it you who wrote this program? because your `myList` is already having that value. Just do `print myList` and you will see it

Comment: This is what error I made. Thanks for that I printed the wrong variable.

Answer (score 2):

you just need to print myList in your program.

```
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence:")
words = sentence.split()
position= [0]
myList = []
[myList.append(x) for x in words if x not in myList]
print(myList)
```

Blockquote

Comment: Up-vote because you only pointed the actual issue in answer i.e *"What I need help with is that I want the program to"* which is OP's program

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
def removeDuplicates(oldList):
    newList = []
    for i in oldlist:
      if i not in newlist:
        newlist.append(i)
    return newList
```

And use it like this:

```
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence: ")

words = removeDuplicates(sentence.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick one-liner. Split by spaces and set finds the unique values:

```
words = list(set(sentence.split(' ')))
print words
```

Comment: Would it maintain the order of word? Also, `.split()` is enough. need not to mention space `' ' `

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't `words` yield your desired result?

```
In [9]: sentence = input("Please Enter as sentence: ")
Please Enter as sentence: 'I like Python'

In [10]: words = sentence.split()

In [11]: words
Out[11]: ['I', 'like', 'Python']
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use **set** command to remove duplicates

```
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence:")
set(sentence.split())
```